# Find the minimum value of array of object with conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

```
    let event = [
    {
        "vendorBidId": 58,
        "participantName": "bro.gee@test.in",
        "bidAmount": 10000,
        "productionRate": 10000,
        "bidTime": "2021-10-21T14:55:05.957324",
        "isYou": false,
        "awarded": false
    },
    {
        "vendorBidId": 57,
        "participantName": "test@gmail.com",
        "bidAmount": 20000,
        "productionRate": 20000,
        "bidTime": "2021-10-21T14:50:24.493522",
        "isYou": false,
        "awarded": true
    },
    {
        "vendorBidId": null,
        "participantName": "bro+2@test.com",
        "bidAmount": 0,
        "productionRate": null,
        "bidTime": null,
        "isYou": false,
        "awarded": false
    },
    {
        "vendorBidId": null,
        "participantName": "bro.hey@test.com",
        "bidAmount": 0,
        "productionRate": null,
        "bidTime": null,
        "isYou": true,
        "awarded": false
    }
]
```

Here I want to find the minimum bidAmount, but after checking below condition,

1. Skip if vendorBidId is null

I tried to do like this.

```
let minimum = event.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev.bidAmount < curr.bidAmount ? prev : curr;
});
```

But and tried to add my condition also. But doesn't work well.

I want just the minimum bidAmount (skip for vendorBidId is null) only.

Comment: That's a simple `if (...)` to check the content. What have you tried so far, and what errors did you get? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> _"**Describe the problem**. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Math.min on a Filter and map

```js
let event = [{ "vendorBidId": 58, "participantName": "bro.gee@test.in", "bidAmount": 10000, "productionRate": 10000, "bidTime": "2021-10-21T14:55:05.957324", "isYou": false, "awarded": false }, { "vendorBidId": 57, "participantName": "test@gmail.com", "bidAmount": 20000, "productionRate": 20000, "bidTime": "2021-10-21T14:50:24.493522", "isYou": false, "awarded": true }, { "vendorBidId": null, "participantName": "bro+2@test.com", "bidAmount": 0, "productionRate": null, "bidTime": null, "isYou": false, "awarded": false }, { "vendorBidId": null, "participantName": "bro.hey@test.com", "bidAmount": 0, "productionRate": null, "bidTime": null, "isYou": true, "awarded": false } ]

const min = Math.min(...event
  .filter(evt => evt.vendorBidId)
  .map(({bidAmount}) => bidAmount)
);  

console.log(min)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `reduce` is a simple approach (if you want the entire object).

If you just need the minimum vakue, you can use `Math.min` after mapping the minAmount key values.

```js
  let event = [
    {
        "vendorBidId": 58,
        "participantName": "bro.gee@test.in",
        "bidAmount": 10000,
        "productionRate": 10000,
        "bidTime": "2021-10-21T14:55:05.957324",
        "isYou": false,
        "awarded": false
    },
    {
        "vendorBidId": 57,
        "participantName": "test@gmail.com",
        "bidAmount": 20000,
        "productionRate": 20000,
        "bidTime": "2021-10-21T14:50:24.493522",
        "isYou": false,
        "awarded": true
    },
    {
        "vendorBidId": null,
        "participantName": "bro+2@test.com",
        "bidAmount": 0,
        "productionRate": null,
        "bidTime": null,
        "isYou": false,
        "awarded": false
    },
    {
        "vendorBidId": null,
        "participantName": "bro.hey@test.com",
        "bidAmount": 0,
        "productionRate": null,
        "bidTime": null,
        "isYou": true,
        "awarded": false
    }
]

const min = event.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev.bidAmount < curr.bidAmount && curr.vendorBidId ? prev : curr;
});

console.log(min);

var minValue = Math.min(...event.map(item => item.vendorBidId ?   item.bidAmount : 0));

console.log(minValue);
```